# Two NIC's - one for Internet, the other for LAN

Tags: networking, internet

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 32bit. I'm trying to accomplish something that I'm sure is simple.
I have two NIC's installed on my PC.

- eth0 - connected to office network with static IP.
- eth1 - connected to Internet via router with DHCP.

I would like to have all regular Internet traffic going through `eth1` and all internal office stuff going through `eth0`. 
From what I have read online so far, I understand that I need to setup a static route. Can anybody instruct me on how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

The link to the geekstuff.com article is a very good explanation but does not describe exactly how to do this for a dual-homed scenario.

Assuming:

eth0 - office network with static IP address      (10.x.x.x addresses); 
eth1 - Internet connection via router with DHCP   (172.168.1.x addresses)

The following worked for me:

```
sudo route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 gw 10.14.21.1 dev eth0
sudo route del default gw 10.14.21.1
sudo route add default gw 172.168.1.1 dev et
```

In my case, Internet access was needed temporarily, so the appropriate files were not modified to make this permanent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what would be the appropriate files to change and which would be the changes?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/route-examples/) article. It describes a scenario similar to what you intend to implement and explains in brief some of the basic concepts behind networking.